# How to get running process in Android?

Tags: android, activity-manager

As of API level 21, getRunningAppProcesses() returns the app itself. How can I get the processes running in the android ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Pass the class that you need to check

Comment: No I don't need the service running app. Even if the app is destroyed the service will be running and your code will only provide that.

Comment: You want to get list of all service running from all apps on phone?

Comment: No I want to get all the apps running in background.

Comment: Well, activity can't run in the background, only service can. So if an app is running in the background then it is that app's service running.

Comment: You didn't get me. What I mean by background is that the app isn't destroyed it's in onPause phase.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it's possible. If it is then I don't know.